# Google maps InfoBox (infowindow) on top of the map (z-index), Yelp.com tooltip effect

Tags: google-maps, z-index

This is a google map with an InfoBox, I want to achieve the Yelp's map tooltip div effect. **In other words I want to position an infoBox on top of a google map**, in order to do that I'm using a google maps InfoBox with a z-index higher than the map z-index, but it is not working, this is the jsfiddle help please,

> http://jsfiddle.net/MdhzR/

In this example I want the yellow container to be on top of the map container and also on top of the gray container, is that possible?. help please!

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
#map_canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 1;}
#z_index_gray {
     position: absolute;
      top: 250px; left: 250px;
      height: 125px; width: 125px;
      background-color: gray;
      z-index: 10;}
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="z_index_gray"></div>
    <p>
```

JS:

```
function initialize() {
                var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307);

                var myMapOptions = {
                    zoom: 15
                    ,center: secheltLoc
                    ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);


                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: theMap,
                    draggable: true,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
                    visible: true
                });

                var boxText = document.createElement("div");
                boxText.style.cssText = "position: absolute;border: 1px solid black;  background: yellow; padding: 5px;z-index: 20;height: 100px; width: 300px;";
                boxText.innerHTML = "City Hall, Sechelt<br>British Columbia<br>Canada";

                var myOptions = {
                    content: boxText
                    ,disableAutoPan: false
                    ,maxWidth: 0
                    ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
                    ,zIndex: 1
                    ,boxStyle: {
                        background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
                        ,opacity: 0.75
                        ,width: "280px"
                    }
                    ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                    ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                    ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(5, 5)
                    ,isHidden: false
                    ,pane: "floatPane"
                    ,enableEventPropagation: false
                };

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    ib.open(theMap, this);
                });

                var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
                ib.open(theMap, marker);
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                initialize();
            });
```

> **JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MdhzR/**

Thanks!
PD. I'm following this infoBox documentation example: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

Answer (score 4):

I found this example from Pamela Fox and it does exactly what I want.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html

I hope it helps to someone else.

Comment: The link is now 404 :-(